# How can I ensure that the Windows Azure Database Cache feature is correctly configured and is running in Orchard CMS?

Tags: azure, orchardcms

We have just recently upgraded a large solution with a number of custom modules from Orchard 1.6 to Orchard 1.7.2. The site is hosted in Windows Azure Cloud Services, over multiple instances.

When I enable a feature, only the instance that receives the post request thinks that the feature is enabled. I'm pretty certain that is because the azure caching isn't correctly configured even though I have enabled the Windows Azure Database Cache feature enabled.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why this could be happening, or if there is any way to test if the Azure caching is correctly configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be happening if you have enabled the feature on the live website. You will need to restart the other instances which have not processed the original request, to let them reload the new settings.

Comment: So to clarify- even with Azure Database Caching enabled, it is normal to have features only enable on the instance that handles the feature enable request?

Comment: Correct, the settings changes are not propagated across instances.

Comment: OK thanks. So can the same be said about adding or editing a widget? Because if I add a widget, it only appears on the instance on which it was added. Which values does the Azure DB Caching feature handle?

Comment: Ah - I thought that this was solved by some of the changes to caching in orchard for 1.7. It is more than a minor ache to go onto each server to update the feature (we have 4), which leaves our sites in an inconsistent state in the meantime. Also - does this happen with widgets or page content - as this would be quite a pain - end users are not going to recycle app pools!

Comment: No, just settings, and new tenants, not content